# ¿Como enviar datos de un formulario a otra pantalla en flutter?

Tags: flutter

Estoy creando una aplicacion que captura una serie de datos mediante un formulario, pero no se como enviar los datos a una segunda pantalla al darle guarda, me gustaria que al dar guardar se abra una segunda pantalla en la cual se muestre una pantalla de bienvenida por asi decirlo que te diga el nombre, el telefono y el correo que se capturo en el formulario.

Este es el codigo del boton guardar:

```
  onTap: (){
    save();
  },child: Container(
        margin: new EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
            Color(0xFF0EDED2),
            Color(0xFF03A0FE),
          ],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft, end: Alignment.bottomRight),
        ),
        child: Text("Guardar",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16),
      ))
    ],
  );
```

Y este es el codigo del metodo save():

```
   if (keyForm.currentState!.validate()) {
     print("Nombre ${nameCtrl.text}");
     print("Telefono ${mobileCtrl.text}");
     print("Correo ${emailCtrl.text}");
         keyForm.currentState!.reset();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Siempre cuando alguien empieza en una tecnología, lo primero que deben hacer es revisar la documentación oficial que provee el mismo framework/herramienta.

Este es el enlace donde indican como pasar datos entre pantallas:

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Ejemplo:

```dart
      // Cuando presiona el botón
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => DetailScreen(datos: "El valor que quieres pasar"),
          ),
        );
      },
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, si lo revisé de hecho ese mismo ejemplo, pero lo que no supe es como adaptarlo a mi código.